# Calculating an ellipsoid with the same distance sum from each point on it's surface to the two foci

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a software engineer and look for the answer to a question which I havent found a solution for. So please excuse my bad mathematical terminology in this question.

I want to generate an ellipsoid around 2 foci points. It should have the following properties:

Every point on the surface of the ellipsoid should have the same combined distance from both focis.
Let S1 be the first foci and S2 the second. The distance r1 is the distance from any point on the eliipsoids surface to foci S1 and r2 the distance from any point on the surface to foci S2.

Then r1 + r2 should be the same for every point on the surface.

In 2D I used the simple Pins-and-string construction, which generates such an ellipse.
For 3D I dont't know how to do it so that i get an ellipsoid with the same properties.
I thought about rotating the ellipse from 2D but my research told me if I do that I dont get such an ellipsoid and that I need to use an iterative approach but I didn't find any specific formulas that would help me to do so.

I'm really desperate and hope a mathematician can help me understand the logic behind an ellipsoid.

Thanks!